# Shorted switch & cannot restore power

Tags: electrical, switch

I have two switches side by side. one controls the ceiling light in the apartment kitchen, the other controls the ceiling fan/light.

I lost power to the ceiling light. since it is a new install I decided to take a quick look without turning off a breaker. I wasn't planning on working on it, only look. What happened is the black live wire came out of the insert. I think I didn't have enough bare wire fir it to be grabbed. Loosening the screws holding the switch in place caused the wire to short out the power to the light and half the apartment, and some of the house it is in. I checked the breakers and none was thrown. I know what breaker it belongs to and turned it in and off. Unfortunately, without success. I checked to make sure it wasn't another breaker and all were normal as I pressed them to the on position.

***Note:*** There are two outside breakers with the two middle switches surrounded by a metal plate, and must be turned in and off simultaneously. The middle two are controllable separately. In discussions it was referred to as possibly being out of 'phase.'

***Additional Possibly Valuable Information***
Some of the power enters the unit from the house (use the same board) through the wall of the kitchen. The plug outlet dies not work, yet it supplies power to about half of the apartment and the fridge and stove that are working. It wasn't affected, but just in case it somehow is relevant I thought I should mention.

Comment: If you think a quick look without removing power was a good idea, especially in an apartment where tampering with the circuits without owner's approval probably violates your lease and may be flat-out illegal... the best advice I can give you is that you don't have the knowledge or. certifications to DIY this. Call a pro. You can't afford _not_ to.

Comment: It is not difficult when you know what you are doing

Comment: Agreed, given that conditional, which clearly didn't apply here.  And given that you are authorized to do the work without breaking your insurance, your lease, the law, .... If you're working on your own house, you only risk your own property and family if you botch it.  In an apartment you're putting other peoples' property and lives on the line, and unless you have whatever licenses/certifications are needed in your area AND have permission from the landlord AND are carrying liability insurance, you really shouldn't be attempting it.